# Ember fixtures on model are not loaded at start

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures

I have an issue regarding load Ember data from an specific model. First of all I must point out that I'm using require.js to load all dependencies. I load all controllers, view, routes and then, I add them to my global Ember app. Moreover, I have a simple model with a few fields as fixtures.

So, the first time something like `App.MyModel.find().toArray().length` responses me 0. But when the app has started, if I try to run this sentence I get the right value.

I've attempted to figure out any event or method (in controller or route) that executes after all but I didn't get it. I've attempted to set the `controller.content` at `App.ready` without successful result

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: I believe the `length` is 0 because `find` returns a promise and  you're trying to access the object's properties while it hasn't been materialized. You should call `find` in [`Route#model`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/), and set the controller content in [`Route#setupController`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe your comment is more than an acceptable answer, you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: Yes @MilkyWayJoe it is exactly that I've been doing but there was no successful

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or add your code here?

Comment: Thanks @MilkyWayJoe I finally found a solution after googling a lot

Comment: didn't know you're using modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was a "fixes set":

1. I had to split the Ember Application Object in order to set first the instance of `DS.Store`, and the add to it the "Models"
2. In the second part of this object I added all the controllers, views, router, etc
3. Finally, when I extended the `DS.Store` object I had to set the attribute `simulateRemoteResponse: true`

The final app.js code was the following:

```
define(
    [ #dependencies ],

    function( #dependencies_objects ) {

        window.App = Ember.Application.create({
            VERSION: '1.0.0',
            LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,

            rootElement: '#app',

            // Store
            store: DS.Store.create({
                revision: 12,
                adapter : DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
                    simulateRemoteResponse: false
                })
            }),

            // Models
            Item: Item  // Where Item is my own model
        });

        App.reopen({
            // Routes
            IndexRoute: IndexRoute,

            // Load routes
            Router: Router,

            // Controllers
            ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend(),
            IndexController: IndexController
        });

    }
);
```